# When running Bibtex with a statement that has a comma at the end, this is obscuring real problems

Tags: bibtex, warnings

When I run bibtex on document with a citation such as `\cite{European00Presidency}` and the .bib entry looks like this:

```
@MISC{European00Presidency,    
  author = {European Council,},
  title = {Presidency conclusions},
  year = {2000},
  keywords = {Lisbon Strategy},
  publisher = {European Council,},
  type = {Government Document},
  url = {http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/ec/00100-r1.en0.htm}
}
```

I get the very unhelpful warning message that " "European Council," **has a comma at the end** for entry European00Presidency" Which i really don't care about. But it hides other warnings such as entry not found or what ever. I would like to turn that warning off in Bibtex. Does anyone know how to do that.

I'm using MikTex 2.9, Jabref 2.9.2 and texmaker 4.1.1

As this is a problem for anyone dealing with large numbers of corporate authors I think there should be an option of changing this

Comment: Testing I see you do get a warning, but am surprised that it would suppress other errors/messages.

Comment: It doesn't suppress the other warnings but I have a large number of corporate authors so the long list of warnings means that it is difficult to find other warnings such as that a certain tag is missing or that the reference wasn't found etc. It is just easier to find the relevant info in a short text, than in a pile of useless warnings. Hope this cleared it up. The proposed solution below works but needs you to modify the bib file, which is a bit of a pain but once done works fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

while this is not clearly documented in the "usual" places, in "guide to latex" by kopka & daly, it is stated in section 12.2.4, regarding names, that

> Anything enclosed in braces will be treated as a single item,
>   something that is used in ambiguous cases, or when the name contains a
>   comma or the word *and*. An example is
>
> ```
> "{Harvey and Sons, Ltd}"
> ```

thus my advice is to omit the comma, but wrap an additional pair of braces around
the element, as

```
author = {{European Council}},
```

Comment: @ic_fl2 The braces are not a work-around for the warning itself: removing the comma does that.

Answer (score 14):

I had the warning after executing Biber.

```
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
```

My code was the following:

```
@Book{jur2009,
    author  = {Jurafsky, D., and Martin, J.},
    year    = 2009,
    title   = {Speech and Language Processing: An Introduction to Natural Language Processing, Speech Recognition, and Computational Linguistics}
}
```

Then I figured out that the cause of this warning is the comma in `D, and`. To separate list of authors, use `and` instead of `,`. For example, `Jurafsky, D. and Martin, J. and Manning, C.` In the above case, removing the comma resolved the problem.

The corrected entry is,

```
@Book{nlp,
    author  = {Jurafsky, D. and Martin, J.},
    year    = 2009,
    title   = {Speech and Language Processing: An Introduction to Natural Language Processing, Speech Recognition, and Computational Linguistics}
}
```

Comment: I've got a couple of these "comma after a name" warnings, too.  It would be very helpful if biblatex (which I'm using) would tell what line of the input file this appears on, or copy the entire line to the .blg file...

Answer (score 0):

This error can be resolved by removing the comma(,) from the entry and replacing it with "and". I guess we can use a comma and "and" together in the BibTex. This worked for me.
For example,
I got an error in the authors' entry,

```
@misc{aian_ref,
author    = "Samantha Artiga , Latoya Hill , Sweta Haldar from KFF",
title     = "COVID-19 Cases and Deaths by Race/Ethnicity: Current Data and Changes Over Time",
url       = "https://www.kff.org/racial-equity-and-health-policy/issue-brief/covid-19-cases-and-deaths-by-race-ethnicity-current-data-and-changes-over-time/"
```

}

Now,

```
@misc{aian_ref,
author    = "Samantha Artiga , Latoya Hill and Sweta Haldar from KFF",
title     = "COVID-19 Cases and Deaths by Race/Ethnicity: Current Data and Changes Over Time",
url       = "https://www.kff.org/racial-equity-and-health-policy/issue-brief/covid-19-cases-and-deaths-by-race-ethnicity-current-data-and-changes-over-time/"
```

}

after replacing the comma with "and" the issue was resolved.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How is your answer different from the answer posted by Sisay Chala six years ago?