# How to find entries with commas at end of name(s)?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I get warnings from biber:

```
Biber warning: [1960] Utils.pm:193> WARN - BibTeX subsystem: warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
Biber warning: [1960] Utils.pm:193> WARN - BibTeX subsystem: author, warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
```

but the bib file I'm using has more than 10,000 entries so manually finding these is not possible. How can I find the entry or entries that cause biber to emit these warnings?

Comment: You can do a regular expression search in almost all editors, or in the terminal on Mac/Linux/Cygwin etc., for author fields that end with a comma. Note that it may be the case that the comma is not really there, and the warning is caused by a problem during processing of the field.

Comment: @Marijn I searched for a comma followed by zero or more spaces, then a "}", which matched nothing. But I still get these warnings.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to have the entry using binary search (i.e. throw away half of the `.bib` file, see if the error persists and repeat). That algorithm needs `$\log_2(n)$` steps, which does take some time with 10.000 entries, but is not impossible.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/60 for why Biber can't provide more specific locations for those warnings.

Comment: It could also be a comma before `and`, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156377/when-running-bibtex-with-a-statement-that-has-a-comma-at-the-end-this-is-obscur.

Comment: Marijn's guess with the `and` (`,\s*and`) is the next thing I would search for after the comma-curly-bracket combination (`,\s*}`).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, searching for the and worked.

Comment: Good to know it is resolved. Maybe we should close this question as a duplicate of the other? I'll propose the closing.

Comment: this is not a duplicate as the question in that one is how to turn the warning off. I asked if it's possible to find the entries that cause these warnings.

Comment: Yes, the duplicate question thingy is wrong. This is not a duplicate of that.